# Configure GNOME fonts using NixOS configuration file

Tags: gnome, nixos

I recently migrated from `Arch Linux` to `NixOS`. While fiddling with `NixOS` configuration, I noticed there is a section to configure the fonts. This is how it looks like on my end:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports = [
    ./hardware-configuration.nix
  ];

  ...

  fonts = {
    enableDefaultFonts = true;
    fontDir.enable = true;
    fontconfig = {
      antialias = true;
      cache32Bit = true;
      # TODO: Set fonts within GNOME Tweaks for the time being
      # defaultFonts = {
      #   monospace = [ "Ubuntu Mono Regular" ];
      #   sansSerif = [ "Ubuntu Regular" ];
      #   serif = [ "Ubuntu Regular" ];
      # };
      hinting.autohint = true;
      hinting.enable = true;
    };
    fonts = with pkgs; [
      noto-fonts
      noto-fonts-cjk
      noto-fonts-emoji
      # noto-fonts-extra
      ubuntu_font_family
    ];
  };
  ...
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to set the `Ubuntu` fonts in the same way I do using `GNOME Tweaks`:

[image]

I wonder if `fonts.fontconfig.defaultFonts` (or any other settings) could be used for this purpose? So far I've tried to do it as such, but they aren't set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether those applications respect the fontconfig configuration. If GNOME tweaks does not do that, configuring fontconfig has no visible effect.

In order to configure GNOME things declaratively, perhaps check out home-manager's dconf options.